# Doppelpunktstellung nach Adverb im Nebensatz

Tags: punctuation, subordinate-clause

Warum ist die Stellung des Doppelpunktes in folgendem Satz richtig?

> "Es ist immer offensichtlicher, dass die unkontrollierte klandestine Immigration, **besser: die organisierte Invasion**, nichts Gutes bringt."
>
> (È sempre più evidente che l'immigrazione clandestina fuori controllo, anzi l'invasione organizzata, non porterà nulla di buono.)

Ich musste zwei Mal den Satz lesen, weil mich der Doppelpunkt gebremst hat. Bricht etwa die höhere Hierarchie dieses Doppelpunktes nicht den Nebensatz entzwei?

<sup>Der obige Satz ist ein Zitat von der [*taz*](http://taz.de/Rassismus-in-Italien/!5316998/) zum Thema Rassismus in Italien. Fettschrift vom OP.</sup>

Comment: Womit belegst du die Annahme, dass der Doppelpunkt "eine höhere Hierarchie" als die Kommas des Nebensatzes (wenn es denn einer ist) hat? Ich finde den Doppelpunkt schon OK, aber hätte statt der Klammerung durch Kommas (um den Einschub ab *besser:*) lieber eine mit Klammern oder Gedankenstrich gesehen - Einschübe mit Kommas sind nicht so gut als solche zu erkennen und ich denke *das* ist eher, worüber ich bei diesem Satz stolpere.

Comment: @tofro Die Hierarchie habe ich vielleicht irrtümlich aus dem Spanischen (und Englischen) importiert. Da bremsen Doppelpunkte mehr als Kommata. Die Sache ist, es gibt ein Assoziativitätsschema in der Deutschen Sprache und dieser Satz hat mir meine Vorstellung von dem Schema gebrochen, daher will ich wissen wo ich falsch liege.

Comment: Wie gesagt, ich finde eher die Klammerung des Einschubs unglücklich als den Doppelpunkt - Ich sehe ein Komma, erwarte einen Nebensatz, beim Doppelpunkt stellt sich dann heraus es war gar keiner, sondern ein Einschub. Dieses "Aufs-Glatteis-Führen" meiner Erwartungshaltung und das anschließende Zurückrudern ist das, was mich beim Lesen stocken läßt.

Comment: Ich habe diese Verwendung des Doppelpunkts schon öfter gesehen und mir nichts dabei gedacht. Ich denke, Regel 34 (http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/doppelpunkt, angekündigte Erläuterung) passt. Für eine "höhere Hierachie des Doppelpunktes" kenne ich keine Regel.

Comment: Dem Doppelpunkt folgt m.W. immer ein neuer Satz, der daher groß zu schreiben ist, womit die Prämisse, dass der Satz richtig sei, falsch ist.

Comment: Die Unsicherheit der Groß-/Kleinschreibung nach einem Doppelpunkt ergibt sich daraus, dass er kein Schlusszeichen, sondern ein Übergangs- und Ankündigungszeichen ist. Dementsprechend schreibt man nach einem Doppelpunkt das erste Wort eines vollständigen Satzes groß, aber klein, wenn es sich um einen Satzteil oder Einzelwort handelt, das kein Substantiv ist. Beispiele: Das Sprichwort lautet: Morgenstund hat Gold im Mund. Eines fand ich merkwürdig: dass niemand davon gewusst haben wollte. Verhalten: sehr gut. (Quelle http://gfds.de/doppelpunkt-gross-kleinschreibung-nach/)

Comment: Wikipedia (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelpunkt) liefert noch zwei weitere schöne Beispiele für Kleinschreibung:

Er rief sie alle zusammen: seinen Koch, seine Frau und ihren Liebhaber.
In Hamburg fand sie, was sie sich sehnlichst gewünscht hatte: eine unterirdische Villa.

Comment: Da ich nicht zur Frage richtig oder falsch antworten kann, hier ein Punkt der bisher kaum erörtert wurde: der Doppelpunkt ist in diesem Fall ein Stilmittel, eben genau um den Leser zu unterbrechen und ihn ganz deutlich darauf hinzuweisen, dass der Autor die "unkontrollierte klandestine Immigration" eher für eine "organisierte Invasion" hält. Mit gängigeren Formen wie der Umschreibung "oder besser gesagt" aus tueftls Antwort oder einem Einschub mit Gedankenstrichen wäre ihm das vielleicht nicht in dem Maße gelungen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[§81 des Regelwerks](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf81.html) befasst sich mit dem Doppelpunkt. Canoo.net hat dann auch noch einen [Beitrag zum Doppelpunkt](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Doppelpunkt.html#Anchor-Man-44867) "mit eigenen Worten".

Zusammenfassend wird der Doppelpunkt verwendet bei:

1. wörtlich wiedergegebene Äußerungen oder Textstellen / Zitat
2. Aufzählungen, spezielle Angaben, Erklärungen
3. Zusammenfassungen des vorher Gesagten oder Schlussfolgerungen

Was dein Beispiel angeht, greift hier wohl (2): spezielle Angabe bzw. Erklärung.

Bevor ich darauf weiter eingehe, halten wir aber erstmal fest:

- Nach einem Doppelpunkt und dem entsprechenden (1) Zitat, der (2) Aufzählung oder der (3) Zusammenfassung ist ein Satz nicht zwangsläufig zu Ende, wenn auch üblich. Es gibt aber meines Wissens keine Regel, die dies erforderlich macht.
  Ein Beispiel dafür genommen von der oben verlinkten canoo.net Seite:

  > Er rief: „So spät!“ und legte beleidigt den Hörer auf.
- Nach einem Doppelpunkt muss nicht zwingend groß geschrieben werden. Nur wenn es sich um einen Ganzsatz handelt, so ist das erst Wort nach dem Doppelpunkt groß zu schreiben. Siehe dazu [§54](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf53-54.html#pgf54).

  > Wird die nach dem Doppelpunkt folgende Ausführung als Ganzsatz verstanden, so schreibt man das erste Wort groß.

  Ich habe im Regelwerk keine Aussage gefunden, die besagt, dass immer groß geschrieben werden muss und demzufolge ist dies nicht gegeben. [Canoo.net fasst auch zusammen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Satzanfang.html#Anchor-Nach-11481), dass nach dem Doppelpunkt in der Regel klein geschrieben wird. Man findet auf den oben verlinkten Seiten auch haufenweise Beispiele, wo eben nicht großgeschrieben ist. Wachsame Augen haben auch bemerkt, dass ich in dieser Antwort auch zweimal nach dem Doppelpunkt nicht groß geschrieben habe.

Zurück zu deinem Satz. Ich denke, dass der Satz absolut in Ordnung ist. Zum besseren Verständnis wäre der Einschub "besser: die organisierte Invasion" sinnvoller mit Gedankenstrichen abgetrennt oder in Klammern eingefügt worden, aber der Verwendung von Kommas ist nichts einzuwenden. Eine weitere Variante wäre gewesen, Anführungszeichen um "die organisierte Invasion" zu setzen. Jede dieser Variante hätte dir geholfen, den Satz auf Anhieb zu verstehen.

Answer (score 5):

Im genannten Satz wirkt der Doppelpunkt klar mit niedrigerer Hierarchie als die Kommata; eine allgemeingültige Hierarchiestufe für Doppelpunkte im Deutschen gibt es meines Wissens nicht. Doppelpunkte geben bei der Aussprache ebenso wie Kommata kurze Pausen an.

Statt der Konstruktion mit dem Doppelpunkt könnte auch *oder besser gesagt, die organisierte Invasion* eingeschoben werden. Dadurch würde die Komplexität des Satzes jedoch noch etwas steigen; auch hier könnte das Komma durch einen Doppelpunkt ersetzt werden, weshalb sich der Schreiber offenbar für die kürzere Form entschieden hat.

Comment: Oh nein, die Pausenregel. Aber im Deutschen? Kommt gar nicht in die Tüte! Mit diesem Ansatz kann man ja nur Komma-Fehler machen. Englisch ist kürzer als Deutsch und kann sich die Pausen vielleicht erlauben. Die haben sowieo keine sinnvolle oder gar einheitliche Kommaregelung, wie man so hört--und vorallem leicht selbst sehen kann. Für  lange Pausen nehme ich dann ein Semikolon, den Gedankenstrich nur für besonders lange Denkpausen oder was? Und der Doppelpunkt--er kennzeichnet natürlich eine Pause (lasst uns an diesem Moment kurz innehalten) die doppelt so lang ist wie die des Punktes